# USB Drive not recognized in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: usb

Last night I attempted formatting my 16GB Flash drive, it did not show any window with the progress of the formatting and I decided to unplug it. The USB drive shows in the disk utility and I formatted it, it also was benchmarked for data read and write speeds. In the terminal the following command were executed and it is not recognized outside of the disk utility:

```
$ df
Filesystem                  1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                          1997996        0   1997996   0% /dev
tmpfs                          403696     6556    397140   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 110615368 39259832  65713504  38% /
tmpfs                         2018460    29420   1989040   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         2018460        0   2018460   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                      482922   158829    299159  35% /boot
cgmfs                             100        0       100   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs                          403696       72    403624   1% /run/user/1000
/home/julio/.Private        110615368 39259832  65713504  38% /home/julio
```

Also used the command

```
$ lsdb
    NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
    sda                       8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk  
    ├─sda1                    8:1    0   487M  0 part  /boot
    ├─sda2                    8:2    0     1K  0 part  
    └─sda5                    8:5    0 111.3G  0 part  
      └─sda5_crypt          252:0    0 111.3G  0 crypt 
        ├─ubuntu--vg-root   252:1    0 107.3G  0 lvm   /
        └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 252:2    0     4G  0 lvm   
          └─cryptswap1      252:3    0     4G  0 crypt [SWAP]
    sdb                       8:16   1  14.6G  0 disk  
    sr0                      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Also used

```
$ mount /dev/sdb
mount: can't find /dev/sdb in /etc/fstab
```

Any idea of how to make this USB drive work?

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a partition on USB since it does not have any partition.

- Open a terminal and type in `sudo gparted`
- In the top right corner, change the `device` to `sdb`.
- If there is any partition, delete that by right clicking and choose delete.
- At this point the whole `USB` should be a `single unallocated block of memory`.
- Right click and create a new partition.
- Set the partition as `primary` and choose a `filesystem` (usually `fat32` or `exfat`).
- Click `Apply` to apply all of the changes.