# Unable to mount location - Can't mount file

Tags: partitioning, mount, ext4

I am aware of [this question with the same title](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249838/unable-to-mount-location-cant-mount-file) which does not solve my problem.

After my USB stick was no longer auto-mounted I thought that maybe a reformating will solve the issue. I tried to partition using `fdisk` and then making the filesystem using `mkfs.ext4` ([guide](https://superuser.com/a/643797)). Though `mkfs.ext4` took an infinite amount of time (over night for 64GB seems to be rather excessive). I also tried `gparted` which also get stuck.

`fdisk -l` displays me the USB stick with correctly partitioned filesystem.

Is there a way to resolve this issue? Or is this a sign that the lifetime of my USB stick has expired?

Not directly related to my question, but I am wondering about it:
Why do I have to partition the stick if I want to use the full USB stick size?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [USB Drive not recognized in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811257/usb-drive-not-recognized-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: As already mentioned above, I also tried `gparted` as suggested in the question you linked but also without success.

Comment: Can you be more precise? When you say "gparted gets stuck" what do you mean? Command line or gui?

Comment: I used the gui. I queued deleting old partition (s.t. I get an unallocated volume) and afterwards write new ext4 partition. Somewhere where within this process it get stuck as the process takes forever. I have the impression, that the problem is writing the new partition.

Answer (score 0):

I've had several similar issues in the past, with sticks that were previously used on Windows by people who doesn't know how to protect their computer from malware (e.g. my mother). I think it has to be some kind of Virus. Once my problem was solved booting Windows and formatting the stick, which I was't able to achieve with gparted. Once the problem was solved connecting the stick via USB cable to the computer. In other cases I just gave up. Those sticks are made to fail, so don't try too hard.